# Run an array based off the value of a variable

Tags: php

I have two arrays. I want only array "one" to run if the variable "purchase" is true. If that variable is false then only run array "two"

I'm a novice at PHP so forgive me if the terminology is wrong. I assume it would involve an if/else statement

```
$purchase = "----";

// This is array "one"
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
"customer" => $customer->id,
"description" => "Single Purchase")
));

// This is array "two"
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
"customer" => $customer->id,
"plan" => $_POST['subscription'],
"coupon" => $_POST['coupon'],
"quantity" => $_POST['quantity'],
"description" => "Subscription")
));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($purchase){
    // This is array "one"
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "customer" => $customer->id,
        "description" => "Single Purchase")
    ));
} else{
    // This is array "two"
    $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
        "customer" => $customer->id,
        "plan" => $_POST['subscription'],
        "coupon" => $_POST['coupon'],
        "quantity" => $_POST['quantity'],
        "description" => "Subscription")
    ));
}
```

If the `$purchase` variable is true then the array one will run else array two block will run

Comment: Thanks but that didn't accomplish what I need. It's still running both of the arrays. I'm trying to run only one of the arrays based on the value of the variable. I could be wording this wrong :/

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you very much